# Getting a random getmapASync null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, nullpointerexception

I'm doing a simple Map View on the island of Java in Indonesia. I'm currently having a problem doing a map fragment right now, specifically in **getMapASync** returning a null pointer reference, according to the logcat.

Here's my code :

```
 private GoogleMap java__island_map;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    SupportMapFragment javamapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.java_island_map);
    javamapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    java__island_map = googleMap;

    LatLng JavaIsland = new LatLng(-7.50166466, 111.257832302);
    java__island_map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(JavaIsland).title("Java Island"));
    java__island_map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(JavaIsland));
}
```

As this isn't a form of child fragment, I tried using **getChildSupportFragment** to no avail. Next, I tried fixing the fragment to become regular **MapFragment**, doesn't work. Here's my XML code :

```
 <fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/java_island_map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

</fragment>
<ScrollView .... etc
```

What did I do wrong here? This will help me a lot, as I will do this for other map-based UIs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving call to getMapAsync() to onActivityCreated()

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `null` before calling the `getMapAsync()`. like following

```
 supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.java_island_map);
 if (supportMapFragment == null) {
     FragmentManager fr = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction ft = fr.beginTransaction();
     supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

     ft.replace(R.id.java_island_map, supportMapFragment).commit();
  }
  supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Hope it helps you.